# How to do Activity profiling in Android

Tags: android

I have developed one android application and now I'm trying to do the profiling of my android application. So for this I got a good link here:

http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/debugging/debugging-tracing.html#format

Using this info I'm trying to profile my activity using Debug class that is in the oncreate() method of my activity. I'm using

```
Debug.startMethodTracing("calc");
```

to start method tracing and add the traces to calc.trace

and I'm stopping the method tracing in my onDestroy().

```
Debug.stopMethodTracing();
```

My problem is when I check the calc.trace, the file is always of 0 size. No traces have been updated, and I don't know why.

In the manifest I have added the required permission for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it is just a typo. Use Debug.stopMethodTracing() in onDestroy(). (note that in you post it is  Debug.startMethodTracing();)
Or may be you activity just don't been destroyed, so yo can try to add Debug.stopMethodTracing() to onPause()

Comment: Hi boulder thanks for the reply, now it is working fine. but the problem is the trace file if it is of size more than 7000 KB ,im not able to view that file using traceview. im getting the following error. outofmemoryError .. java heap space error.. why is that?

Comment: Try this startMethodTracing(String traceName, int bufferSize). Or traceview simple doesn't support traces that big.

Comment: HI boulder i got a good solution at the following link for the exception im getting http://twigstechtips.blogspot.com/2011/04/java-exception-in-thread.html

Comment: Thank you this one can be useful.